# TCppWebBrowser vs TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, twebbrowser

What is the difference between `TCppWebBrowser` and `TWebBrowser` components in C++Builder 2010 and above? There is no mention of `TCppWebBrowser` in the help, where `TWebBrowser` has regular help section.

So, which one should I use and is there any real difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` is used in Delphi, `TCppWebBrowser` is used in C++.  They are essentially the same thing.